# why this error "TypeError: execute expected at most 2 arguments, got 3"?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)", username, password)
```

as a beginner, I am trying to make a sign up form for my first web app using Flask and python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using different arguments for each variable, you need to put all variables in an array or a tuple:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)", (username, password) )
```